# .net core build error when building docker image missing Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I'm trying to build my .net core project onto a docker container but it seems like it can't find Newtonsoft.Json which I thought was included in the asp.net core

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 58373
EXPOSE 44370

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestCode/TestCode.csproj", "TestCode/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TestCode/TestCode.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TestCode"
RUN dotnet build "TestCode.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestCode.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestCode.dll"]
```

I'm getting the following error when trying to build 
Error       Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Can you check that the you haven't got a reference to `NewtonSoft.Json` in your project? This is normally caused when the project is looking for the DLL instead of the NuGet package.

Comment: Other than using statements for NewtonSoft.Json, I don't see any direct reference to it. The error did seem to go away when I check generate nuGet package on build and it went away. Am I just masking an issue or was that the right solution?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: In my case the asp.net app itself was using NewtonSoft.Json 12 which obviously conflicted with Docker Desktop using version 11... - I cannot claim to understand what exactly was happening, downgrading to 11 in the app helped thou.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, When used `JsonProperty` in a class,

Visual Studio intellicode auto-filled,

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Then during `docker build`,

> warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Newtonsoft.Json". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk.

When I checked, found out that the Visual Studio added an **Assembly Reference** to `Newtonsoft.Json` (you can find this by expanding **Dependencies** node in the solution explorer in Visual Studio). And I was using Linux images.

So in order to solve this, I removed the **Assembly Reference**, and added nuget package `Newtonsoft.Json`, then the `docker build` was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. Update NuGet package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets to latest version and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

I Don't know why, but I hit this issue because of my tests projects. Once I removed my tests from the release configuration (meaning "I Don't want the test assemblies in my publish folder"), the docker file worked great. xUnit using coverlet for code coverage in net core 3.1, might help someone someday, I almost lose it.

EDIT:
Doing further research I found this is an issue in the coverlet package to track code coverage. Can be fixed using `<IsPublishable>false</IsPublishable>` as Billy Braga mention here https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet/issues/1045

Answer (score 0):

1 way is to have your other project be part of your solution and reference it as a project reference.
or
2nd way, as a quick resolution what I did and it worked for me, is after COPY . . is to add another copy command in the docker file like:
COPY ./bin/Debug/.../your-referenced-dll-name.dll .
--Hope this helps